# Can we use Polly retry instead of ExponentialBackoffRetry in Service Bus Topic Trigger Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, polly

We are using Service Bus Topic Trigger Azure function, and we’re planning to implement a simple behavior in Azure Function, if there is any exception during processing/handling we want to postpone the next retry from some time.

Currently we're planning to use `[ExponentialBackoffRetry]` attribute, as shown in the below code.

But Can we use [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) retry instead of `[ExponentialBackoffRetry]`? Basically which approach would be idle for our requirement - `[ExponentialBackoffRetry]` or [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) retry

Below is our Service Bus Topic Trigger Azure Function:

```
 [FunctionName(nameof(CardGroupEventSubscriber))]
 [ExponentialBackoffRetry(5, "00:00:04", "00:01:00")]
 public async Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceBusConfigOptions:TopicEventTypeName%", "%ServiceBusConfigOptions:TopicEventTypeSubscription%",
            Connection = "ServiceBusConfigOptions:ConnectionString")]
            string sbMsg)
        {
            try
            {   
                var message = sbMsg.AsPoco<CardGroupEvent>();

                _logger.LogInformation("{class} - {method} - {RequestId} - Start",
                   nameof(CardGroupEventSubscriber), nameof(CardGroupEventSubscriber.RunAsync), message.RequestID);

                _logger.LogInformation($"Started processing message {message.AsJson()} with", nameof(CardGroupEventSubscriber));

                var validationResult = new CardGroupEventValidator().Validate(message);

                if (validationResult.IsValid)
                {
                    await _processor.ProcessAsync(message);
                }
                
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Unable to process card group event {sbMsg.AsJson()} with {nameof(CardGroupEventSubscriber)}," +
                    $" ExceptionMessage:{ex.Message}, StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}");
                throw;
            }
            #endregion

        }
```

Comment: Polly gives you more fine grained control how do you want to setup your retry logic. **When**: Should it trigger for any exception or just some specific ones? Should it trigger if the response statuscode is xyz? Etc... **How**: Should simple use an exponential back-off or with a jitter? Should it be aware of a circuit-breaker? Should it be aware of a ratelimiter's RetryAfter header value? Etc... It could be also dynamically parameterized, you could use predefined hooks to added logging and so on.... I hope you get the idea :)

Comment: @PeterCsala, actually it should trigger only for specified exceptions/status code that is the plan. Could you please share any link or reference where it is showing how can we replace exponential back-off with Polly. That would be very helpful.

Comment: [This is the official documentation of Polly's exponential back off](https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry#wait-and-retry-with-exponential-back-off). But if you share with us how would you like to setup your retry we can help here to set it up properly.

Comment: @PeterCsala, I have gone through above documentation url, but it is not showing how can we implement exponential back-off for azure service bus topic triggers.

Comment: I've updated my post to detail how to combine multiple policies

Comment: @PeterCsala Thank you so much! for your guidence. I am working on the implementation as you suggested. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246597/discussion-between-rakesh-kumar-and-peter-csala).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polly's policies can be defined and used in an imperative way.
*Whereas the `ExponentialBackoffRetry` attribute can be considered as declarative.*

So, let's say you want to define a policy which

- Do an exponential back-off with jitter
- Only if a `CosmosException` is thrown
  then you do that like this:

```
const int maxRetryAttempts = 10;
const int oneSecondInMilliSeconds = 1000;
const int maxDelayInMilliseconds = 32 * oneSecondInMilliSeconds;
var jitterer = new Random();
var policy = Policy
  .Handle<CosmosException>()
  .WaitAndRetryAsync(
      maxRetryAttempts,
      retryAttempt =>
      {
          var calculatedDelayInMilliseconds = Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt) * oneSecondInMilliSeconds;
          var jitterInMilliseconds = jitterer.Next(0, oneSecondInMilliSeconds);

          var actualDelay = Math.Min(calculatedDelayInMilliseconds + jitterInMilliseconds, maxDelayInMilliseconds);
          return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(actualDelay);
      }
  );
```

- I have implemented here by my own the exponential back-off

  - The main reason is to reduce the number of packages (so, we don't need the `Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry`)

Now let's apply this to your `RunAsync` method

```
[FunctionName(nameof(CardGroupEventSubscriber))]
public async Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceBusConfigOptions:TopicEventTypeName%", "%ServiceBusConfigOptions:TopicEventTypeSubscription%",
    Connection = "ServiceBusConfigOptions:ConnectionString")]
    string sbMsg)
  => await GetExponentialBackoffRetryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => RunCoreAsync(sbMsg));

private async Task RunCoreAsync(string sbMsg)
{
    try
    ...
}
```

- I have moved the original `RunAsync`'s code into the `RunCoreAsync` method
- I have replaced the `RunAsync` implementation with a one liner which creates the above policy then decorates the `RunCoreAsync`

---

Just a side note: In case of CosmosDb it might make sense to handle the rate limiting/throttling in a different way.

When I receive a `CosmosException` and the `StatusCode` is 429 then use the `RetryAfter`'s Value to delay the retry, something like this

```
var policy = Policy
    .Handle<CosmosException>(ex => ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(maxRetryAttempts,
       sleepDurationProvider:(_, ex, __) => ((CosmosException)ex).RetryAfter.Value,
       onRetryAsync: (_, __, ___, ____) => Task.CompletedTask);
```

---

**UPDATE #1**: Combining the two policies

If you want you can combine the above two policies. All you need to do is to make them independent. So, whatever happens only one of the policies should be triggered. The easiest solution is to pass this `ex => ex.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests` predicate to the exponential backoff policy

```
IAsyncPolicy GetExponentialBackoffRetryPolicy()
    => Policy
    .Handle<CosmosException>(ex => ex.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(
        maxRetryAttempts,
        retryAttempt =>
        {
            var calculatedDelayInMilliseconds = Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt) * oneSecondInMilliSeconds;
            var jitterInMilliseconds = jitterer.Next(0, oneSecondInMilliSeconds);

            var actualDelay = Math.Min(calculatedDelayInMilliseconds + jitterInMilliseconds, maxDelayInMilliseconds);
            return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(actualDelay);
        }
    );

IAsyncPolicy GetThrottlingAwareRetryPolicy()
    => Policy
    .Handle<CosmosException>(ex => ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(maxRetryAttempts,
        sleepDurationProvider: (_, ex, __) => ((CosmosException)ex).RetryAfter.Value,
        onRetryAsync: (_, __, ___, ____) => Task.CompletedTask);
```

In order to combine these two into one you have [many options](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap), I suggest to use the `Policy.WrapAsync`

```
IAsyncPolicy retryPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync(GetExponentialBackoffRetryPolicy(), GetThrottlingAwareRetryPolicy());
//OR
IAsyncPolicy retryPolicy = Policy.WrapAsync(GetThrottlingAwareRetryPolicy(), GetExponentialBackoffRetryPolicy());
```

Here the ordering does not matter since they are independent policies.

Comment: I have added these two policies in the CardGroupEventSubscriber class(same class where we have RunAsync method), but it is not working as expected. I have set Max delivery count 2 in the Service Bus Topic subscriptions, and I am throwing InvalidOperationException explicity. But function retry immediately and it is not waiting

Comment: @RakeshKumar Why do you throw InvalidOperationException? The policy has been setup for CosmosException not for IOE.

Comment: I tried with GetExponentialBackoffRetryPolicy, which is for all other exceptions. But still it is not waiting for rety.

Comment: @RakeshKumar both of the policies are setup only for CosmosException. See the Handle builder methods' generic parameter. They differ in the StatusCode under the CosmosException.

Comment: this is how I am calling in RunAsync method -> await GetExponentialBackoffRetryPolicy().ExecuteAsync(async () => await RunCoreAsync(sbMsg));

Comment: Thank you so much I got it, quick question, If I want to move policies into separate class, then that class must be static. and these two policy method also static. Am I right?

Comment: @RakeshKumar If you would make these methods static then you don't need to instantiate the surrounding class to access them. But if you want to write unit tests then static is not your friend.

Comment: I agree with you, now i am planning to create separate class and I'll move these two policies into that, and I'll access these policies through interface injection. Will that fine, what's your thought on that? for example IRetryPolicy.GetExponentialBackoffRetryPolicy and IRetryPolicy.GetThrottlingAwareRetryPolicy

Comment: @RakeshKumar Yepp, that would be fine

Comment: As you suggested I can use Interface to access these two policies and I can create separate class, so should I register IRetryPolicy interface as Singleton? for example: builder.Services.AddSingleton<IRetryPolicy, RetryPolicy>();

Comment: @RakeshKumar Yes Singleton is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thakns! for your suggetion.